# LaTeX xsim: printing only even/odd number answer

Tags: conditionals, exercises, xsim

I am writing exercises sheets for my student and I want to print only solutions to odd (or even) numbered exercises using LaTeX xsim.  I have searched on Google and looked in the xsim manual, but couldn't find anything.  So is there an easy way to print only odd numbered solutions with xsim?

Thanks and have a great day
Nicolas Leduc

Answer (score 2):

Just an attempt:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/within=section,
}

\begin{document}
\section{title}
\begin{exercise}
  first exercise
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  first solution
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}
  second exercise
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  second solution
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}
  third exercise
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  third solution
\end{solution}

\section{title}
\begin{exercise}
  first exercise
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  first solution
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}
  second exercise
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  second solution
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}
  third exercise
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  third solution
\end{solution}

\ForEachUsedExerciseByID{%
  \ifodd\GetExerciseProperty{counter-value}\relax
    \XSIMprint{solution}{#1}{#2}%
  \fi
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you also do that or similar for a book with a list of end of chapter exercises and then a final "Solution to odd exercises" chapter?

Comment: @JPMD It seems to me the current example can already do this, you only need to change `exercise/within=section` to `exercise/within=chapter`. If you encountered any problems, feel free to post a follow-up (new) question and add a comment here to get me informed.